# Proxied Object Assignment Type Error TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a cache that my app uses and the cache is wrapped in a Proxy that manages the expiration validation.

Here are some of the List definitions from my Lists.d.ts file for reference but I don't think the issue exists here.

```js
interface MetaData {
  Title: string | null;
  FileSystemObjectType: number;
  Id: number;
  // ....
}

// The CreationProps types just define the fields in the object
type DeviceCreationProps = {
  Model: string;
  Manufacturer: string;
  // ...
};

type CommentData = MetaData & CommentCreationProps;
type DeviceData = MetaData & DeviceCreationProps;
type UserData = MetaData & UserCreationProps;

type ListDataMap = {
  Comments: CommentData;
  Devices: DeviceData;
  Users: UserData;
};

type ListName = keyof ListDataMap;
```

Now in my ListItemCache.ts file I have the following code:

```
type CacheExpirationMapValue = {
  // [list name] : expiration date object
  [List in ListName]?: Date;
};
const CacheExpirationMap: CacheExpirationMapValue = {};

type RawListItemCacheValue = {
  // [name of list]: array of list items
  [List in ListName]?: ListDataMap[List][];
};
const RawListItemCache: RawListItemCacheValue = {};

const maxAge = 1000 * 60 * 5;

// This is a proxied object that allows us to handle the expirations when fetching cached objects
const ListItemCache = new Proxy(RawListItemCache, {
  set<List extends ListName>(obj, prop: List, value: ListDataMap[List][]) {
    const expires = new Date(Date.now() + maxAge);

    CacheExpirationMap[prop] = expires;

    obj[prop] = value;

    return true;
  },

  get(obj, prop) {
    const item = obj[prop];
    const now = new Date();

    if (item && !!CacheExpirationMap[prop] && CacheExpirationMap[prop] > now) {
      return item;
    }

    return [];
  },
});

export default ListItemCache;
```

Everything is fine and I don't get any issues in this file, but when I try to set the value of the cache in another file for instance:

```
export default function usePopulateCache<List extends ListName>(list: List) {
  const { sp } = useContext(SPContext);
  useEffect(() => {
    sp.web.lists
      .getByTitle(list)
      .items<ListDataMap[List][]>()
      .then((items) => {
        ListItemCache[list] = items;
      });
  }, []);
}
```

I get the following error in the assignment:
[image]

I'm not sure why this is because the List type that indexes both of them is the same and `RawListItemCacheValue[List]` should be the same as `ListDataMap[List][]` according to its type definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem here is that `RawListItemCacheValue[List]` is not the same as `ListDataMap[List][]`, even though it really looks like it is.

If you check the error you will see whats the difference is in that line:
`CommentData | DeviceData | UserData is not assignable to type CommentData`.

What this means is that when yo do this:

```js
type RawListItemCacheValue = {
  // [name of list]: array of list items
  [List in ListName]?: ListDataMap[List][];
};
```

somehow you are telling `tsc` this:

```js
type RawListItemCacheValue = {
  [CommentData]?: ListDataMap[CommentData][];
  [DeviceData]?: ListDataMap[DeviceData][];
  {...}
};
```

So the key and the value are correlated.

The problem is that when you do `ListDataMap[List][]` with `List` being === to `keyof ListName`, this value can be anyone on `ListDataMap`. So when you do `ListItemCache[list] = items;` you are really doing:

```js
ListItemCache['CommentData' | 'DeviceData' | 'UserData'] = (CommentData | DeviceData | UserData)[]
```

So `tsc` complains for that because `ListItemCache['CommentData'] = DeviceData` would be a possible combination which is wrong.

Comment: This makes sense, but how would I go about making the mapped type properly so that each key corresponds to the correct value type rather than the mixing that's happening now?

Comment: In my opinion, the best solution would be to have the specific type returned from the `sp.web.lists.getByTitle` call instead of the unio type. But I'm not sure if that's possible since I don't know that implementation